# Pattern search with more than one mismatch allowed

Tags: perl

I am  trying to find pattern search with specific condition: we have to find starting positions. 
Also more than one mismatch is allowed ie. it should be run for 1 or 2 or 3 mismatch.
i.e. for 1 mismatch one character of the pattern may or may not match while matching 
with the sequence. As same for 2 mismatch two  character of the pattern may or may not match while matching
with the sequence. And so on.

```
output: should be written into a file in a table format:
e.g,  pattern may be TGCA and sequence may be ATCGATGCATATCGATC....]

finding TGCA  in sequence ATCGATGATATCGATC  will result in
S.no  position       the_matched_pattern
1      5                 TGCA
```

The match and mismatch may come in any position (i.e, in same position or in different position). How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is the longest common sub-sequence problem. Do some research on the "Smith-Waterman" algorithm -- you should probably implement that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Actually LCS *is* on CPAN: [Algorithm::LCS](http://search.cpan.org/~joesuf/Algorithm-LCS-1.04/LCS.pm) [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3A%3ADiff)

Comment: thank you Anthony Blake for your reply. But i have to only find out more than one mismatch in the pattern . Smith-Waterman_algorithm is big problem. so can you help me in exact syntax for my probleme.